# Pivot table for single table in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, pivot-table

I'm trying to add a multi-level categories in my website. where a category can have **multiple child** and also have **multiple parent**. It's look like many to many relationship in Laravel and I have to use a pivot table.

So that i create a table called **categories** and also a pivot table **categories_reltionship** like below. Now my question is how i will make this many to many relationship with this single table in Laravel.

```
categories table
==================
id    title
===   ======
1     title_1
2     title_2
3     title_3
4     title_4
5     title_5
```

```
categories_relationship table
==================
parent_id    child_id
==========   ======
1            2
1            3
4            2
4            3
5            2
5            3
```

Comment: I would suggest having a look at nested sets: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Answer (score 2):

You can have methods like below on `Category` model :

```
//This will get you the list of categories
public function categories()
{
    return ($this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Category', 'App\Models\CategoryRelation', 'child_id', 'id', 'id', 'parent_id'));
}

//This will get you the list of children
public function childs()
{
    return ($this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Category', 'App\Models\CategoryRelation', 'parent_id', 'id', 'id', 'child_id'));
}
```

on `CategoryRelation` model :

```
class CategoryRelation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories_relationship';
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem

Note : I suggest you to have 3 tables for [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships,

Answer (score 0):

in many to many relationship **you should to have three tables**. I hope that help you below example.
in our scenario as mentioned we have three tables with user , role and pivot names that each user can many roles and each role independent to many users.

```
user table have my_user_id(optional name) and other need column.
role table to have my_role_id (optional name) and other.
pivot table includes my_user_id , my_role_id.
```

in **User model** your codes should like below:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
      {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'pivot', 'my_user_id', 'my_role_id');
      }
}
```

in **Role model** your codes should like below:

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
      {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'pivot', 'my_role_id', 'my_user_id');
      }
}
```

You can also refer to laravel official documentation:
[many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)